# Enabling TFS documents feature using Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, team-explorer, azure-devops

Is there a way to use [TFS Documents feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181484.aspx) in [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx) (Visual Studio Team Services previously known as Visual Studio Online or Team Foundation Service)

If so, how?

Comment: I believe that feature is only available to on-premises installations, although I can't find a comparison chart to confirm

Comment: ...and it has been removed from TFS 2018.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sharepoint-dashboards/manage-documents-and-document-libraries?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only available in an on-premise TFS installation, because it has a requirement to link up with a Sharepoint server. You can't use VSTS with Sharepoint, and it's increasingly uncommon to find people using Sharepoint in conjunction with on-premise TFS, because the only real thing Sharepoint provides at this point is document management.

Comment: Thanks. So what are the existing solutions for document management in VSTS?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using Sharepoint for document management. The integration points don't really relate to document management, it's more like work tracking / dashboards. Luckily, TFS has way better dashboards for work tracking built in now.

Comment: I use my Office365 sharepoint with my VSTS. No integration needed, side by side.